# how to get the values in a row in a table in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i have this code and i want to do now is once i click the a href="submitreserve.php">Reserve< all the values in the selected row will be save to $_POST so that i can fetch them in my submitreserve.php code.

```
echo'<table>
                <tr>
                <th> ID. </th>
                <th> Year Level </th>
                <th> Course </th>
                <th> Description </th>
                <th> Action </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>';

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$con){
        die('Could not connect to database' .mysql_error());
        }
        else{
        mysql_select_db("enrollment", $con);
        }       
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubjectoffer where course = '$course' and semester = '$sem' and year = '$year'");
        if(!$result){
        die('Invalid query:' .mysql_error());
        }
        else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo'<td class="offerCell">'.$row['offer'].'</td>';
        echo'<td class="yearCell">'.$row['year'].'</td>';
        echo'<td class="courseCell">'.$row['course'].'</td>';
        echo'<td class="descCell">'.$row['sub_desc'].'</td>';
        echo'<td><a href="submitreserve.php" class="insertButton">Reserve</a></td>';
        echo'</tr>';
    }
    }
}
        echo'</table>'; 

    ?>
```

my submit.php code must be like this.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$desc = $_POST['description'];

$sql=mysql_query("insert into tbldepartment (id, year, course, description) values('$id','$year','$course','$desc')");
```

something like that. anyone can help me here? i am stuck in this for almost 2 weeks. please help me.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize your data. I recommend switching to `mysqli` and then using `$year = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['year'];` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending something via $_POST, then you need a form.

Use something like:

```
<form method="post" action="submitreserve.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" />
  <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2014" />
  <input type="hidden" name="course" value="course here" />
  <input type="hidden" name="description" value="very descriptive" />
  <button type="submit">Reserve</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have some JavaScript code, something like:

```
<a href="submitreserve.php" onclick="reserve(val1, val2, val3, val4)">Reserve</a>
```

Have your php code put the parameters in for the reserve function call.

Then define a JavaScript function to do the POST request (sample provided below using jQuery):

```
function reserve(id, year, course, desc) {
    $.post( "reserve.php", {
        id: id,
        year: year,
        course: course,
        description: desc
    }, function() {
        alert("success");
    }, function() {
        alert("error");
    })
}
```

How to do a post request using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/